# Else/If statement help in swift

Tags: if-statement, swift

I'm getting an error when I try to use an if/else statement in Xcode 6 with Swift. This is what I have

```
} else if countElements(sender.text) == 1, 2
```

It's telling me:

> Type 'String!' does not conform to protocol '_CollectionType'

How can I compare two values on one line?

Comment: Yes, I need it to look at 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "||" = "or"

```
} else if countElements(sender.text) == 1 || countElements(sender.text) == 2 {

}
```

Comment: Is that the easiest way to do it? Or can I use something like } else if countElements(sender.text) == 1, 2?

Comment: No. you can't make two comparisons like this.

Comment: yeah, like on apple's Dev library they have their integer values together like that, except they were using "let" statements. Such as let x = (1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer correctly shows the way to make 2 comparisons in Swift, but this can be done in a single statement thanks to Swift's pattern matching operator. For example:

```
if 1...2 ~= countElements(sender.text) {
    println("count is 1 or 2")
}
```

Basically, the provided statement is true if the number of characters in your string is inclusively between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `contains` global function, providing it a range and the element to check for inclusion:

```
contains(1...2, countElements(sender.text))
```